# MemoryError when generating every possible combination of letters and numbers with a length of 6

Tags: python, python-3.x, out-of-memory, combinations, permutation

I am trying to output a list of every possible 6 length combination of with the alphabet and numbers.

I have tried MANY different types of codes to this, and this one seems to be the best but it doesn't work for the long length I am using it for.

```
import itertools
import pprint
letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M",
          "N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
          "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
pprint.pprint(list(itertools.product(letters, repeat=6)))
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
MemoryError
```

It does work with repeat set as anything less than 5.

How can I fix this? Is there an easier or better way to get the same result? Would it be possible to just output this to a text file instead of having to print it? I don't care if there are repeats or not, but it would be preferred if there aren't any.

This site: textmechanic.com/Combination-Generator.html also does the same thing I want, but it doesn't work with the large amount of objects I am using and the length of the combinations. If there is already a list like this, that would do.

Or is it just impossible to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially asking for pre-generating all such combinations in a single list and then print them in one go.

What you can do is to avoid this by not calling `list(...)` but instead printing them on the fly, while the iterator is generating them.

This is one example. It is not in the original format, but it gets the job done.

```
import itertools
import pprint
letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M",
          "N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
          "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
for item in itertools.product(letters, repeat=6):
    pprint.pprint(item)
```

Comment: Awesome! This works great and just like I wanted. But how can I get this to be outputted onto a .txt file? I know how to write to a file but which part of this do I write? Do I just do file.write(pprint.pprint(item)) or can I do variable = pprint.pprint(item) then write that? edit: nevermind, i got it to work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to create a list containing 36 ** 6 = 2176782336 tuples of 6 1-character strings. That's more than 2 billion (2 thousand million). That requires at least 210 GB of memory, *just* to hold the tuple objects (each 104 bytes small on my Mac).

Don't try to produce a list; print the values as they are generated then discard them again:

```
for combo in itertools.product(letters, repeat=6):
    print(''.join(combo))
```

To write this to a file, write the `str.join()` result plus a newline:

```
with open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for combo in itertools.product(letters, repeat=6):
        outfile.write(''.join(combo) + '\n')
```

This takes very little RAM, but you will need 14GB of disk space to store the 2 billion times 7 characters (including the newlines).

Comment: Yeah, I calculated 2176782336 but I didn't know that would mean 12GB of memory. Bit of topic but do you mean I would need 12GB of RAM or just hard drive space? Just intrested.

Comment: @Yami: That's 12GB of disk space. It requires at least 113GB of memory for the Python objects.

Comment: @Yami: sorry, that should be 210GB; I used the size of an empty tuple, but with 6 values the memory footprint of the tuples alone is 104 bytes each.

Comment: @Yami: 2 billion 6 character strings, plus newlines, makes for 14 billion characters, actually, so you'd need 14GB of disk space for all those strings.

Comment: wait does that mean that when it is done it will take 210GB of disk space??? What exactly do you mean by memory for the Python objects? When I print all this or save it to a file how much space will it take? Thanks for this information.

Comment: @Yami: To build *one big list* in RAM, you need 210GB of RAM. No modern home PC or laptop can hold that much memory, so that's why you get your MemoryError. If you were to generate the strings one by one as I do in my answer, and you were to write all those to a file object you don't need much RAM at all, but you do need 14GB of disk space.

Comment: i did the file output but it still gave me a memory error

Comment: @vanetoj: Then something else is wrong. The code in my answer (with the right imports and `letters` set up as in the question), running in Python 3.9, currently requires 5.3MB when running on macos 11.5.2. My test process has already written out 75MB of data, and the memory use is stable.